# Mootools login facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, mootools, facebook-login

In a simple webpage I want user to be able to login with his facebook acount which is in javascript and mootools framework. The code is:

```
    var moofb = new MooFB.Base(APP_ID);
    $('login').addEvent('click', function() {
        moofb = new MooFB.Base(371204703259599);
        moofb.login(function(response) {
            if(response.session) {
                console.log('ifNr1');
                if(response.perms) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

        }.bind(moofb));
    });

    $('perms').addEvent('click', function() {
        moofb.login(function(response) {
            if(response.session) {
                if(response.perms) {
                }
            }
        }.bind(moofb), {perms: 'read_stream,publish_stream'});
    });
```

But login does not work. May I know where the problem is?

Edit: As stated in the duplicate question, there is an error *MooFB.Base is not a constructor*.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: unfortunately nothing happened!!

Comment: I copied the code from Mootools website and just changed the App_ID to mine.

Comment: Can you show the link you copied from?

Comment: https://mootools.net/forge/p/moofb

Comment: I guess these two questions are the same, and the error you describe in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159210/moofb-base-is-not-a-constructor is the one you got here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not include the [two dependencies listed](https://mootools.net/forge/p/moofb) :

- Core/Class
- Core/Object

This is why you get the error *MooFB.Base is not a constructor*.